# Read a list input from using the StdIn.readf function

Tags: scala, shell, input, stdin

What is the propper way of read a list input using the readf function?
The [Scala Standard Library](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.3/scala/io/StdIn$.html#readf(format:String):List%5BAny%5D) shows that the sintax is:

```
def readf(format: String): List[Any]
```

but I'm not finding to introduce on the *Format* field and always get the error:

*Solution.scala:11: error: not found: value format
val arr = scala.io.StdIn.readf(format:String)*
when try to store in arr list of Int.

Answer (score 0):

the scaladoc said :

> `def readf(format: String): List[Any]` Reads in some structured input
> (from the default input), specified by a format specifier. **See class
> java.text.MessageFormat for details of the format specification**.
>
> format the format of the input.
>
> returns a list of all extracted values.
>
> Definition Classes StdIn Exceptions thrown java.io.EOFException if the
> end of the input stream has been reached.

So, go to your browser, search "java.text.MessageFormat", and find it :
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html